# How to display numbers in Arabic in Client Report Definition (.RDLC) files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I am using microsoft report in visual stdio 2010 and I want to display numbers in Arabic like this (٠‎ , ١‎ , ٢‎ , ٣‎ , ٤‎ , ٥‎ , ٦‎ , ٧‎ , ٨‎ , ٩‎)
I searched on this site and other sites but could not find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I never used `rdlc` but I think this is a `Culture` issue.

Check this blog post for [how to generate arabic numbers in .net](http://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/archive/2009/06/27/displaying-arabic-number.aspx) and look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/archive/2009/06/27/displaying-arabic-number.aspx#7135645) comment also.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "ar"
```

Answer (score 0):

in properties set

- language = ar;    such as ar_IQ
- NumeralVariant = 3;

use arabic language config in client device